# Send url param from form_tag Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

this is my case:

```
I'm in /car
```

and I want to pass a car model through a form like:

```
/car/:model for example /car/bmw+z4
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_tag(get_model_path, :method => 'get') do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field, :model %>
<% end %>
```

And an error message says:

```
No route matches {:action=>"get_model", :controller=>"cars"} missing required keys: [:model]
```

All this without model or activerecord, becouse is an API consumption.

Any idea?

Comment: did you create the routes for this or not ???

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: get 'car/:model', to: 'cars#get_model', as: 'get_model'

Comment: This is the route get 'car/:model', to: 'cars#get_model', as: 'get_model'

Answer (score 0):

Yes pass it :

```
<%= form_tag(get_model_path(model: 'name'), :method => 'get') do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field, :model %>
<% end %>
```

Here is what I reproduced and also fixed. Look the routes

```
$ rake routes | grep car
get_model GET        /car/:model(.:format)   notifications#get_model
```

Now look at the console:

```
2.2.1 :001 > app.get_model_path
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"get_model", :controller=>"notifications"} missing required keys: [:model]
2.2.1 :002 > app.get_model_path(model: "foo")
 => "/car/foo"
```

I have in my *routes.rb* file :

```
get 'car/:model', to: 'notifications#get_model', as: 'get_model'
```

Answer (score 0):

most simple way to pass any value from form is to use [hidden_fields](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field).So in your form...

```
<%= form_tag(get_model_path, :method => 'get') do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field, :model %>
   <% f.hidden_field(:hidden_value, :value=>"MyModelValue")%>
<% end %>
```

**so at the controller,you can get the value using:-**

```
##to get MyModelValue
model_value=params[:MODEL][:hidden_value]
```

BUT if you want to pass values visible in url while submitting form..then all all form values will get passed along with url which is not good when it comes to security.That's why every form should be submitted using **POST** and not **GET**.its your call :)